# Regex: match X pattern but not Y

Tags: regex

What is the most *efficient* way with regex to match:

> **test**
>
> **test** case
>
> tester

The last one should not match.

Comment: Read a manual.  There's something called a `word boundary`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a word boundary:

```
/test\b/
```

This means that the word must end after `test`.

Comment: If by `break` you mean `end`, then yes I agree +1.

Comment: @pguardiario Yes, I suppose that is more correct, since *break* usually means separating a word when it would normally run on.

Answer (score 1):

```
\btest\b
```

`\b` is the word boundary anchor.